# Weird word or percentage regex case

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse and capture groups in expressions like:

- abc = def
- abc = 10
- abc = 10%
- abc = 10.0
- abc = 10.0%

But I'm unable to match the % cases with regex below:

```
(\w+) *= *(\w+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iu0Rd05zjQfoyeR0)

And what is most surprising is that I can match percentages if I stop accepting words — removing the `\w+`:

```
(\w+) *= *(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?)
```

I've used debuggex and regex101 to understand why this happens but to no success so far.

Comment: `(\w+) *= *(\w+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?)(?=\n|$)`

Comment: You need the global flag. In regex101, you can set it when you type g in the second box (next to the one with your regex). Also, \w is sufficient as it also accepts digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
/(\w+) *= *(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?|\w+)/
```

i.e. match your numbers before `\w+` in alternation since `\w` also includes digits.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vH2cG4/1)

Comment: i was about to post the same regex... also saved  on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rX7aN3/1).

Answer (score 1):

Add `(?=\s|$)` at the end and it should work.

```
 (\w+) *= *(\w+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?)(?=\s|$)
```

[example](https://www.debuggex.com/r/22cP2oMhso1fAXF6)

Answer (score 1):

You've got some working answers and suggestions here, but the simplest, and most effective performance wise, is to simply test for the most complex variation first. Like...

```
(\w+) *= *(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?|\w+)
```

Simply testing for the decimal number first will match it if it can, otherwise continue with the *word* alternation.

This is done in 15 steps, while e.g. `(\w+) *= *(\w+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?)(?=\s|$)` takes twice that.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vC0yL5/1).

Comment: As far as I remember, you wouldn't care about *performance* if OP does not express it clearly. *Everything's going to change.*

Comment: @revo The advantage in performance is just a happy circumstance from the simplicity of the *fix*, that when *choosing*  between two working solutions with the correct outcome, at least in my case, would tip the scale. (I.m.o. you should never ignore performance. It might not matter at the moment, but if you can have it for free (or cheap), why not take it into consideration?)

Comment: and in fact performance gets its most meaning on complex situations and I don't know what you mean by others solutions, but yours is @anubhava's one. Two minutes late in party, better to delete answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed the `\w+`. That matches digits as well and is tried first.
While `\w+` matches greedily, the *complete* expression does not. So `\w+` matches `10` (out of `10.0%`) and the match succeeds. Since we have a success, there's no need to try the alternate path of `\w+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?`.

---

Reordering the regex works:

```
(\w+) *= *(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?|\w+)
```

matches `abc = 10.0%` completely.

---

Another option would be to add an anchor. If this expression needs to match complete lines, add `$`, otherwise add a (non-grouping if needed) expression of what you expect to find after your match, for instance `(?:\s|$)`, making the complete expression:

```
(\w+) *= *(\w+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?)(?:\s|$)
```